OpenAI Assistant - working for one API_Key but not for another one?
i have the following simple assistant using the gpt-4o model -
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from openai import OpenAI

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fn = os.path.join(path, ".env")
load_dotenv(fn)
CHATGPT_API_KEY = os.environ.get("CHATGPT_API_KEY")
client = OpenAI(api_key = CHATGPT_API_KEY)

fn = os.path.join(path, "workText.txt")
vector_store = client.beta.vector_stores.create(name="HTML-File")
file_paths = [fn]
file_streams = [open(path, "rb") for path in file_paths]
file_batch = client.beta.vector_stores.file_batches.upload_and_poll(
  vector_store_id=vector_store.id, files=file_streams
)
print(file_batch.status)
print(file_batch.file_counts)
# exit()

print(f"Preparing assistant")
assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
  name="HTML Analyse Assistant",
  instructions="You are a machine learning researcher, answer questions about the provided text-file",
  model="gpt-4o",
  tools=[{"type": "file_search"}],
)
assistant = client.beta.assistants.update(
  assistant_id=assistant.id,
  tool_resources={"file_search": {"vector_store_ids": [vector_store.id]}},
)

question = """
What is the name of the location?
"""

print(f"Preparing thread")
thread = client.beta.threads.create()
print(f"Preparing question")
results = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
  thread_id = thread.id,
  role = "user",
  content = question
)
print(f"Running for answer")
run = client.beta.threads.runs.create (
  thread_id = thread.id,
  assistant_id = assistant.id
)
while run.status not in ["completed", "failed"]:
  run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve (
    thread_id = thread.id,
    run_id = run.id
  )
if run.status == "completed":
  results = client.beta.threads.messages.list(
      thread_id=thread.id
  )

# resultAnswer = results.data[0].content[0].text.value
fn = os.path.join(path, "result.txt")
with open(fn, "w", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
  lines = f.writelines(str(results))

I have several openai API-Keys and it works fine for one of them with this result output:
SyncCursorPage[Message](data=[Message(id='msg_Z6iImlhDNFDmXoCszSl8hOrp', assistant_id='asst_eYsWBFev7jeZZC3MRyZ9PuJK', attachments=[], completed_at=None, content=[TextContentBlock(text=Text(annotations=[FileCitationAnnotation
(end_index=117, file_citation=FileCitation(file_id='file-v3Y3HH9Kd0L2doxuoRVNU6kL'), start_index=99, text='【4:0†workText.txt】', type='file_citation')], 
value='The name of the location is "Benediktinerabtei Gerleve" which is located in Billerbeck, Deutschland【4:0†workText.txt】.'), type='text')], created_at=1729687317, incomplete_at=None, incomplete_details=None, 
metadata={}, object='thread.message', role='assistant', run_id='run_6KbPCSO8VqIP0bbqFjuSp4fV', status=None, thread_id='thread_aaRH59cvaPGh5L0J8WIviBBU'), Message(id='msg_GPAug3kAr7GSRSEuIPRUmYvc', assistant_id=None, 
ttachments=[], completed_at=None, content=[TextContentBlock(text=Text(annotations=[], value='\n\nWhat is the name of the location?\n\n'), type='text')], created_at=1729687313, incomplete_at=None, incomplete_details=None, 
metadata={}, object='thread.message', role='user', run_id=None, status=None, thread_id='thread_aaRH59cvaPGh5L0J8WIviBBU')], object='list', first_id='msg_Z6iImlhDNFDmXoCszSl8hOrp', last_id='msg_GPAug3kAr7GSRSEuIPRUmYvc', has_more=False)

But with another API-Key it seems not to work - i get no data output -
Message(id='msg_NCxFnnQPXL0gKhsxE2hJhYWh', assistant_id=None, attachments=[], completed_at=None, content=[TextContentBlock(text=Text(annotations=[], 
value='\nWhat is the name of the location?\n'), type='text')], created_at=1729696968, incomplete_at=None, incomplete_details=None, metadata={}, 
object='thread.message', role='user', run_id=None, status=None, thread_id='thread_puBTFtaoMvauMBO2D6Wc2ylr')

Why is this working with one API-Key but not with the other one...?

Hello, are all your keys associated with a gpt-4o deployment? the model being hardcoded, there may be some compatibility issues. Also, very basic but have you check the validity of all the keys before trying your code ?

Where can i associate an API-Key with a gpt-4o deployment?
And how can i check the validity of a key?

So, I have never directly used an openAI API key (I always went with cloud providers API keys), but I would say from the openAI owner account, this can be customizable.
Now, to "test" the validity of a key, you can try a sample code with a basic completion example, see the openAI quickstart guide : https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart. I hope it helps

I'm noticing that you set your variable results twice:
results = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
  thread_id = thread.id,
  role = "user",
  content = question
)

So the content of your first results variable should be the output you see in your second run.
Then you have:
while run.status not in ["completed", "failed"]:

But you only set a new value for results if the status is completed. That makes me fairly confident your second run had status as failed. I can't tell you why it failed because you didn't print any of the logs from the assistant. Could you try printing client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=thread.id)?

finally, I think I found the problem.
The request was indeed ending with the status "failed." To see more information, I needed to output the error code and error message using these additional lines:
print(run.last_error.code)
print(run.last_error.message)

With that, I saw the error message:
rate_limit_exceeded
Request too large for gpt-4o in organization org-uethKLI2dw4Lq0j8f8KFjaBp on tokens per minute (TPM): Limit 30,000, Requested 30,480. The input or output tokens must be reduced for the request to run successfully. Visit https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits to learn more.
With this, I found a workaround. According to the rate limits at: https://platform.openai.com/settings/organization/limits,
I changed the model to “gpt-4o-mini,” which has a 200,000 TPM limit (instead of 30,000 TPM as it is with the “gpt-4o” model).
I still don’t understand why this issue occurs with “gpt-4o” using one API key but not another. However, at least I think I have a workaround.
